# Please explain set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) line of Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, zip

After investigating how to create a zip file with Powershell I found the following very helpful [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx) which describes how to create a zip file using Powershell with the following line of script:

```
set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
```

This works like a charm, problem is I simply don't understand how it works. Could I please get a breakdown of what this does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using `("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))` as the value to `set-Content`, we are simply adding the file header and creating a 0 byte `.zip` file.

To understand this, you may want to read under the section file headers:

- [Magic number (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
- [ZIP (file format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format))

> Headers in ZIP files begin with "PK" (50 4B), the initials of Phil
>   Katz, author of DOS compression utility PKZIP.